# Problem with the screen in elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno, display, graphic-drivers, graphics, intel

I just install elementary OS Juno on my Hp 14 laptop. It generally works, but from time to time I get a white or green line at the top of the screen, I think that the problem is the graphic card, it is an Intel graphic card

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 3185  
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )  
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)  
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.06hz  
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 600 (Geminilake 2x6)  
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.8
```

I do not know How to solve the problem, but I would really like to stay with this Os because I think that it is great

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a system update, also maybe try checking the display settings. If both are normal I would try looking at your bios.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but both the settings seems fine with me.
What should I look for in the bios?
It does not bother me too much, I am just afraid the the display might burn out or stop working altogether.
Thanks.

Comment: There should be some display settings . Also try checking the settings in another display management app in elementary is

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know which setting I should be looking for...

Comment: @Matteo go to system settings> display